# Cannot upload some images in Stack Overflow for Teams, but can on this meta

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I just signed up for teams (Basic), but am a seasoned SO user in my private life with a private profile, so I know *how* to upload images.

I started with an image I took on my phone, which was about 4 MB, 4032x3024. Knowing the 2 MB limitation, I compressed it with an image compressing app but maintained the resolution. I got it reporting 1.98 MB so I tried to upload it. It would let me select the image and click upload, but would fail after upload with the error message:

> Image uploads are limited to 2 MiB; please use a smaller image

I compressed the original with tighter settings and got it to 1.6 MB, but got the same issue. I thought it was the mobile site acting up, so tried on desktop with the same image and still got the same error. I then tried a different image that was much smaller, 87 KB 960x640, and it did successfully upload.

All images except the 4 MB original successfully upload to the public meta.

I don't know if this is a bug or by design, but it certainly seems like the error message is in conflict with reality; the image is under the max size of 2 MiB.